# Visual Studio Oracle Database (ODP.NET, Managed Driver) - Error TNS_ADMIN (11G Database)

Tags: oracle, odp.net

I'm developing an app in Visual Studio 2019 that connects to a Oracle Database(11G);
I have to use the "Managed Driver". All my setups are correct.
I couldn't find any solution.
[image]

All my setups are correct.
I couldn't find any solution.Help Please.

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots. Use formatted text, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Comment: What is the connection string?

Comment: Sorry for the screenshot.

Comment: Here is the connection string.

 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="orcl" providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" connectionString="Data Source=orcl;User Id=QRTECH;Password=QRTECH" />
  </connectionStrings>

Comment: But this does not match to the error message you have.

Comment: Here is the link directory in the tnsnames.ora file;
orcl =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST =  127.0.0.1)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )


where am i doing wrong?

Comment: Again, don't paste screenshots (you can edit your question), which hides the relevant stuff. The Window with the error does not look like raised from the code, it is not clear where it is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

In the "Connection type:" dropdown if you select "TNS Alias" then you have to setup a `tnsnames.ora` file and specify a TNS_ADMIN environnement variable that point to your Oracle client installation folder.

The easiest way is to select "Direct connection" in the drowdown and specify all the connexion parameters (server, port, ...)